# finding out the maximum number if cost is associated with using each digit

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization, knapsack-problem, greedy

I have been given the total money I have. Now I know the cost it takes to write down each digit (1 to 9). So how to create a maximum number out of it? Is there any dynamic programming approach for this problem?

Example:

total money available = 2
cost of each digit (1 to 9) = `9, 11, 1, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 6`
output:33

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need dynamic programming, just do the following:

- Pick as many of the digit that costs the least as you can afford.
- Now you have a number (consisting of only 1 type of digit).
- Replace the first digit with the greatest possible digit that you can afford
- If you have money left, do the same for the second, and the third and so on, until you run out of money.

**Why this works:**

Consider that `11111` > `9999` and `91111` > `88888`, or, in words, it's best to:

- Pick as many digits as possible, which is done by picking the cheapest digits.
- Then replace these digits, from the left, with the highest valued digit you can afford (this is always better than picking a few more expensive digits to start).

**Optimization:**

To do this efficiently, discard any digits that cost more than a bigger digit: (because it's never a good idea to pick that one instead of a cheaper digit with a bigger value)

```
Given:
9, 11, 1, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 6
Removing all those where I put an X:
X, X, 1, X, 5, X, X, X, 6
So:
1, 5, 6
```

Now you can just do binary search on it (just remember which digit which value came from) (although, for only 9 digits, binary search doesn't really do wonders for the already-minor running time).

**Running time:**

`O(n)` (with or without the optimization, since 9 is constant)

Comment: Can't prove, but I think those replacements can't be done in polynomial time.

Comment: @JuanLopes Well, for each digit, you only need to look through the 9 possible digits and find the highest one you can afford. Why doesn't it look like constant time per replacement?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code implemented on the algorithm proposed by **[Bernhard Baker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/bernhard-barker)** answer.
The question was asked in my hackerank exam conducted by Providence Health Services. The question is commonly asked in interview as **Largest Number of Vaccines**.

```py
    total_money = 2   
    
    cost_of_digit = [9, 11, 1, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 6]
    
    # Appending the list digits with [weight, number] 
    k=1
    digits=list()
    
    for i in cost_of_digit:
        digits.append([i,k])
        k+=1
    
    #  Discarding any digits that cost more than a bigger digit: (because it's never a good idea to pick that one instead of a cheaper digit with a bigger value)
    i = 8
    while(i>0):
        if digits[i][0] <= digits[i-1][0]:
            del digits[i-1]
            i-=1
        else:
            i-=1
    
    # Sorting the digits based on weight
    digits.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
    
    max_digits = total_money//digits[-1][0] # Max digits that we can have in ANSWER
    selected_digit_weight = digits[-1][0] 
    
    ans=list()
    
    if max_digits > 0:
        for i in range(max_digits):
            ans.append(digits[-1][1])
    
    # Calculating extra money we have after the selected digits
    extra_money = total_money % digits[-1][0]
    
    index = 0
    
    # Sorting digits in Descending order according to their value
    digits.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
    
    while(extra_money >= 0 and index < max_digits):
        temp = extra_money + selected_digit_weight # The money we have to replace the digit
        swap = False # If no digit is changed we can break the while loop 
        
        for i in digits:
            # Checking if the weight is less than money we have AND the digit is greater than previous digit
            if i[0] <= temp and i[1] > digits[-1][1]: 
                ans[index] = i[1]
                index += 1
                extra_money = temp - i[0]
                swap = True
                break
        if(not swap):
            break
    
    if len(ans) == 0:
        print("Number cannot be formed")
    else:
        for i in ans:
            print(i,end="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

with

- Cost = Digit cost
- Value = Digit number (9 is better than 1)

then sort in decreasing number.

Comment: knapsack involves creating a 2-d array an the limit on total money available is 10^6.how to handle this?

Comment: I didn't see your edit with repeated numbers. So I think that Dukeling's answer is good.